# Why have Force Sensitive Children been deposited/hidden on Desert Planets?

Tags: star-wars

Anakin, Luke, and now Rey, are all found on these desert planets.

Why? Does the inhospitable attributes of the planet help hide Force Sensitives?

Comment: Nice. No though. Leia!

Comment: Their innate hatred of sand will ensure they'll get off-world once they're old enough to do so?

Answer (score 1):

### In-universe

- **Anakin is unknown**.

  The Will of the Force. Maybe simply because the best match for a mother that Midichlorians found was there already. Maybe random. Maybe because Force Ley Lines intersect on Tattoine, considering **just how much stuff goes on there** (we have Anakin, Luke, A'Shard Hett, Skippy the Jedi Droid all originating there; Jabba the Hutt running the planet; Kuat being interested in it).

  Just to clarify - Force Ley Lines aren't actually a *thing* in canon to the best of my knowledge. Just my personal theory that can explain in-universe why ALL the important &*(t in the Galaxy containing millions of star systems happens on like 20 of them, with 80% happening on 5 of those.
- **Luke is because his family is there** (Owen and Beru Lars, <strike>though they aren't blood relatives so Anti-Voldemort spell doesn't work</strike>)

  > Bail stood, ... "Thank you, that’s all. What of the boy?”
  > “**Cliegg Lars still lives on Tatooine, I think—and Anakin’s stepbrother … Owen, that’s it, and his wife, Beru, still work the moisture farm outside Mos Eisley …**”
  > “**As close to kinfolk as the boy can come,” Yoda said approvingly**. “But Tatooine, not like Alderaan it is—deep in the Outer Rim, a wild and dangerous planet.”
  > “Anakin survived it,” Obi-Wan said. “Luke can, too. And I can—well, I could take him there, and watch over him. Protect him from the worst of the planet’s dangers, until he can learn to protect himself.”
  > (*ROTS novelization by Stover*)

  An extra plus is that it's far away from anything, so less chances of him being accidentally found - OR making his way unsupervised into some sort of trouble. But that's just side benefit.
- **Rey: Unknown as of 2016/01 Disney canon**.

  There's a chance that it might be because Lor San Tekka is already there, but that is a very vague and un-substantiated theory.
- Very explicitly, I have NEVER encountered any hint in canon of the idea that a desert planet hides Force sensitive children. On the contrary, we specifically have hints that lush life on Dagobah helped hide Yoda (+Darkside cave); and Leia is hidden in teeming masses of Alderaan.

  If anything, life-poor desert Rim planet would be counterproductive, as there are so much fewer lifeforms to distort the Force.

### Out of universe

- Because the movies are intended to heavilt mirror each other. Luke, his father Anakin, and his (whether biological, or at least spiritual), heir Rey, all are very similar in their Hero's Journey; and an origin on a tough desert planet reinforces that parallelism.
- And as your question mentioned, there's a popular story archetype of a tough inhospitable environment raising a tough fighter. From Dune (Fremen on Arrakis, and explicitly reinforced as in-universe archetype by Duke Leto [choosing them because Emperor Padishah's Sardaukar similarly arose out of Salusa Secundus](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Salusa_Secundus/XD))

  Similarly, we have similar **in-universe-placed** hints at the archetype inserted into Disney Canon itself. In Luceno's novel *Tarkin*, Emperor Palpatine explicitly tells Vader to respect Tarkin, **because** among other things, Tarkin survived his trials on Eriadu.

Comment: The novelisation says that Tatooine was chosen (for Luke) because it's outside Empire control and far from the core worlds.

Comment: Okay I get why Luke was placed where he was, but Leia was put with a Senator!  He was high profile person and maybe even near the Emperor. Wasn't the Senate dissolved in Episode IV? So he must have had visitors to his home world that were from the Emperor, like Vader, who might have sensed Leia.                                                                                                                   Why didn't Yoda have her sent to another barren out of the way planet also?

Comment: @ObiJax-san - which is EXACTLY why I said that "barren planet" wasn't the main reason. Being with loving family was.

Comment: @DVK Anakin wasn't born on Tatooine. He was born elsewhere and sold with his mother into slavery, whose masters then brought them to Tatooine for resale.

Comment: @DVK And the Force doesn't work in the sense that some story universes' magic do. Ley lines and nexus as they are conventionally defined don't exist in Star Wars. The Living Force is emitted by all life, and it feeds the Cosmic Force which permeates and binds all matter. Planets that are abnormally full of life tend to be stronger in the Force, so a desert planet would actually be the exact opposite. History also plays a part, particularly in how certain planets like Morribund and Dagobah are strong in the dark side, an aspect of the Force that does not naturally exist.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - I like my theory better :)))  At least it explains why EVERYTHING happens around a few places, in a super-large galaxy.

Comment: @DVK - I get the loving family part. Wouldn't there be the possibility of loving family in the outer planets?  And why didn't Darth Vader sense her force abilities after interrogating her? Did Yoda have some kind of Force vision about where to place Anakin's children? Could it be that Yoda did have such a vision and he knew Vader would find one of his children, yet he didn't know if it would be Luke or Leia, so he chose the weaker midichlorian-count one of the two and put that one with in the reach of Vader?  (I like over thinking these things....) :-)

Comment: @ObiJax-san - they also needed someone they **trusted**, not just a random loving family. Bail Organa was the person they trusted the most in the Galaxy after each other - and he **volunteered** to take Leia

Comment: @thegreatjedi -  What if the existence of such ley lines is part of the Cosmic force? And Nexuses form at the more hospitable planets?  ;-)

Comment: @ObiJax-san well, even if they do, desert planets like Tatooine and Jakku are far from what would be where they would occur. DVK's hypothesis seeks to explain why so many major events happen at a few planets, mostly desert ones, and his argument would have suggested the exact opposite should have been the case.

Comment: @ObiJax-san Plus, if nexus and ley lines do exist, it is the presence of life that create them, not the other way round. And also, the Force is more akin to an omnipotent god that permeates all rather than a collection of "hotspots" around which the fates write history. Note that some planets become strong in the Force AFTER historical events left their mark. The Force reacts to these events. The Force tends to have a mind of its own in governing the fate of the galaxy. Remember, "let the Force flow through you and guide you." It's kinda like what some people in church say on Earth...